# Como faço para finalizar o loop usando while em um determinado tempo?

Tags: python, loop, while

Esse código é um exemplo, preciso fazer ele finalizar em algum momento usando while

```
while True:        
        #Clicar no link da planilha
        pyautogui.click(x=542, y=255)
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(x=542, y=255)
        pyautogui.press('left')
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    
        #Acessar o site pelo chrome
        pyautogui.click(x=741, y=357)
        pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 't')
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(2)
    
        #Localizar situação cadastral
        pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'f')
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.write('Situacao')
        pyautogui.press('esc')
        pyautogui.doubleClick(x=704, y=466)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    
        #Colocar dados no excel
        pyautogui.click(x=542, y=255)
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.click(x=542, y=255)
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.press('f2')
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
        time.sleep(2)
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.press('up')
        pyautogui.press('alt')
        pyautogui.press('c')
        pyautogui.press('zc')
        pyautogui.press('o')
        pyautogui.press('u')
        pyautogui.press('n')
        pyautogui.click(x=752, y=231)
        pyautogui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'w')
        time.sleep(5)
```

Eu uso o `time.sleep` no final para poder apertar o botão de finalizar.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Cara, fiquei curioso quanto ao seu código. Mas eu sugiro você olhar sobre webscrapping e pandas, creio que vai te atender melhor do que comandos de pyautogui.

Answer (score 3):

Se vc deseja parar a execução do programa em um determinado tempo, faça da seguinte forma usando o module `time`. Você irá definir o tempo para condição de parada `timebreak` em segundos, após isso deverá iniciar seu timer `timestart` e por fim irá subtrair o tempo percorrido com o tempo de inicio, segue o exemplo:

```
import time

# define tempo para condição de parada em segundos
timebreak = 30

#Iniciar temporizador
timestart = time.time()

while True:
    #Realizar tarefa desejada
    ##########################
    
    # pegando tempo percorrido
    timenow = time.time()
    elapsedtime = (timenow - timestart)    

    # validando condição de parada 
    if(elapsedtime >= timebreak):
        print("parando...")
        break
```

Comment: Poderia vir a ser uma resposta que ganhasse muitos positivos.